# Rational approximations to $\sqrt 2$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I find this problem is very interesting, but now I can't solve it.

Given $n$ a positive integer, let $$f(n)=\min_{m\in\Bbb Z}{\left\lvert\sqrt{2}-\dfrac{m}{n}\right\rvert}.$$ If there is a sequence of positive integers $n_{1}<n_{2}<\cdots<n_{l}<\cdots$ and there is a constant $C$ such that

$$f(n_{i})<\dfrac{C}{n^2_{i}},i=1,2,\cdots,$$

prove that there exists some $q>1$ such that $$n_{i}\ge q^{i-1},i=1,2,\cdots.$$

Comment: This is [related](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalApproximation.html).

Comment: I believe that Newton's method  converges upon a solution quadratically, most of the time.

Comment: The question is not really about finding good rational approximations to $\sqrt2$. That can be done either using continued fractions or expanding $0\approx (\sqrt2-1)^n=a_n-b_n\sqrt2$ with integers $a_n, b_n$ and using $a_n/b_n\sqrt2$ (leads to the same set of approximations IIRC). The question is about the growth of denominators within any sequence of good approximations (here *good* means that error is quadratic reciprocal as a function of the denominator).

Comment: @BabyDragon: Are you talking about the iteration $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=(a_n+2/a_n)/2$? It does converge quickly, but also the denominators grow very fast. The game here is to keep the error as small as possible while keeping denominators also small.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was perhaps too hopeful that this may give a method for constructing such sequences. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @BabyDragon: Your sequence may work here. I don't know :-) The other suggested methods do work. To OP: I think that I have seen a result like this in some chapter on Diophantine approximation, but couldn't find it. Sorry. I deleted my own answer, as it doesn't really help here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Approximate $\sqrt{2}$ by a continued fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  once you have found one set of $m,n$ that is close, the next one is $m+2n,m+n$.  These are the convergents to $\sqrt 2$ from the continued fraction: $(1,0), (1,1), (3,2), (7,5) \ldots $  You can show these get close to $\sqrt 2$ rapidly.

Comment: By extension of this, for any number $x$, and starting with ${m,n} = {1,0}$, using the formula for the convergent series for each subsequent set ${m+xn, m+n}$; you'll find that $m/n$ converges to $\sqrt x$